# How to exclude an autoTestFixture when executing a specific test file using Playwright/Typescript?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm currently using Playwright Test for my automation testing needs and have come across a situation where I need to exclude an autoTestFixture from being executed when running a specific test case involving GraphQL requests.

In my test suite, I have an autoTestFixture that sets up the test environment by navigating to the base URL. However, I have a particular test case that performs GraphQL requests using the gqlServices.sendGqlRequestWithVars function. Since this test case doesn't require the autoTestFixture, I want to exclude it from being executed in this scenario.

Fixture File:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK8IH.png)

Spec File:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEShe.png)

Could someone please guide me on how to exclude the autoTestFixture from being executed when running the specific test case involving GraphQL requests? Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I expected that by using the use function with the skip option set to true, the autoTestFixture would be excluded from execution when running the specific test case involving GraphQL requests. However, this doesn't seem to work as intended.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't import test from that fixture in your test file where you don't need it. Use below:

```
import test from '@playwright/test'
```

Instead of:

```
import test from "../../src/app.poc.utils/fixtures";
```

Comment: Thank you bro, is there any other way to achieve this? because I'm using a fixture to import my graphql pages as well. 

`gqlServices: async ({}, use) => {
    await use(new GqlServices());
  },

  gqlQueries: async ({}, use) => {
    await use(new GqlQueries());
  },`

Comment: You are welcome.They don't have to be the same fixture.

Comment: You may have two different fixtures for two separate requirements.